# Does C# have a equivalent to Objective-c's category?

Tags: c#, objective-c

I'm looking for a equivalent to the Objective-c's Category for C# language.

Comment: If you elaborate on what that is, you might get more responses, because people can help you without knowing objective-c

Comment: @Daniel: the existing answers probably give the game away, but since I don't know much C# and it may help: in Objective-C, categories add new methods to a class at runtime. So you're not subclassing (which is useful if the object is created by code you can't change), just adding functionality. Underneath it's achievable because all method calls are looked up dynamically in Objective-C; you can just add a few extra methods whenever you want — either through a nice, syntactically clean category or by dropping down to the C-level interfaces to the runtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't add methods to a class, however you can use extension methods to achieve similar effects.

make a static class, with a static method. The static methods first argument is marked with "this" and the method is decorated to the classes with the type of the argument.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

This method will then be available on all instances of the type String. However you still have to have the extension class available through your usings.

The example is taken from Microsoft's own documention available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing to [Objective-C Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html) in C# is [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Note that **C# is a statically typed language** and doesn't use dynamic dispatching like Objective-C does. That means that **method resolution is performed at compile time** and not at runtime, like you are used to in Objective-C.

**Related resources:**

- [The Objective-C Programming Language: Categories and Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)
- [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Don't categories allow you to add methods to existing classes without subclassing them? If so then extension methods would be the C# equivalent. They won't replace existing methods though and are subject to a few constraints.